# Headless Buckminster RCP Product Generation Fails

Tags: eclipse, rcp, product, buckminster

I try to set up a headless RCP Build with Buckminster.

My Project exists of about 10 subprojects. The Product Definition is based on features and its located in an plugin.
I have two features. One feature have all the plugin-projects and the other feature has some other plugins.

So far I dont automated anything. I just followed RalfEberts Tutorial and created a Feature, that includes all required plugins and that includes my two features as included Feature. My Target Definition is my local eclipse folder with all available plugins.

With the Buckminster-Eclipse Plugin I created the site.p2. Afterwards I try to generate the exe and so on with the director call in the prompt.

The Problem is, that the generated data is not equal to the generated data from the Eclipse Product export wizard. Thats why my application starts and crashes a few seconds later.

For example I have two exe files (my application exe and a eclipsec.exe). Also there is no features folder, which should include my two features and the org.eclipse.rcp feature. The configuration and p2 folder content is different too.

Does somebody have an idea wheres the problem? The Export with the Product Wizard in Eclipse works perfect.
Thanks!

**Edit**

Ok, now my application dont crashes and I try to integrate Buckminster into Jenkins. I created a product.ant, cspec, cquery and rmap file. 
My Target Definition rcp.target contains paths to my libs. Actually Buckminster finds every component, except org.eclipse.rcp.
Org.eclipse.rcp is a jar-file, which is located in my lib, but he dont finds it. I tried severel things, like put the org.eclipse.rcp to an other place and changing my rmap, but I always get the same result.

Here is the Jenkins Output:

```
 INFO:  importtargetdefinition '-A' '/D:/Jenkins/workspace/Buckminster/de.tdb.build/rcp.target'

 INFO:  import '/D:/Jenkins/workspace/Buckminster/de.tdb.build/buckmister.cquery'

 ERROR   [0011] : No suitable provider for component org.eclipse.rcp:eclipse.feature was found in resourceMap file:/D:/Jenkins/workspace/Buckminster/de.tdb.build/site.rmap

 ERROR   [0011] : No suitable provider for component org.eclipse.rcp:eclipse.feature was found in searchPath resources

 ERROR   [0011] : Resolution attempt ended with exception: Provider local(file:///D:/Jenkins/workspace/Buckminster/org.eclipse.rcp/): Missing CSpec source required by component type eclipse.feature

 ERROR   Provider local(file:///D:/Jenkins/workspace/Buckminster/org.eclipse.rcp/): Missing CSpec source required by component type eclipse.feature

 ERROR   [0011] : Resolution attempt ended with exception: Provider local(file:///D:/Jenkins/workspace/Buckminster/de.tdb.dependencies/lib/org.eclipse.rcp/): Missing CSpec source required by component type eclipse.feature

 ERROR   Provider local(file:///D:/Jenkins/workspace/Buckminster/de.tdb.dependencies/lib/org.eclipse.rcp/): Missing CSpec source required by component type eclipse.feature

 ERROR   [0011] : Resolution attempt ended with exception: Provider local(file:///D:/Jenkins/workspace/Buckminster/de.tdb.dependencies/lib/plugins/org.eclipse.rcp/): Missing CSpec source required by component type eclipse.feature

 ERROR   Provider local(file:///D:/Jenkins/workspace/Buckminster/de.tdb.dependencies/lib/plugins/org.eclipse.rcp/): Missing CSpec source required by component type eclipse.feature
```